# What is canActivate and canDeactivate in routing?

Tags: angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateViaAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

What is the meaning of `canActivate` and `canDeactivate` properties?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 10):

**Controlling Access to or from a Route**

To control whether the user can navigate to or away from a given route, use route guards.

For example, we may want some routes to only be accessible once the user has logged in or accepted Terms & Conditions. We can use route guards to check these conditions and control access to routes.

Route guards can also control whether a user can leave a certain route. For example, say the user has typed information into a form on the page, but has not submitted the form. If they were to leave the page, they would lose the information. We may want to prompt the user if the user attempts to leave the route without submitting or saving the information

**Registering the Route Guards with Routes**

In order to use route guards, we must register them with the specific routes we want them to run for.

For example, say we have an accounts route that only users that are logged in can navigate to. This page also has forms and we want to make sure the user has submitted unsaved changes before leaving the accounts page.

In our route config we can add our guards to that route:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AccountPage } from './account-page';
import { LoginRouteGuard } from './login-route-guard';
import { SaveFormsGuard } from './save-forms-guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomePage },
  {
    path: 'accounts',
    component: AccountPage,
    canActivate: [LoginRouteGuard],
    canDeactivate: [SaveFormsGuard]
  }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Now LoginRouteGuard will be checked by the router when activating the accounts route, and SaveFormsGuard will be checked when leaving that route.

**Implementing CanActivate**

```
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from './login-service';

@Injectable()
export class LoginRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

   constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.loginService.isLoggedIn();
   }
 }
```

**Implementing CanDeactivate**

```
export interface CanDeactivate<T> {
  canDeactivate(component: T, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:    RouterStateSnapshot):
       Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean;
 }
```

We can use that component to determine whether the user can deactivate.

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountPage } from './account-page';

@Injectable()
export class SaveFormsGuard implements CanDeactivate<AccountPage> {

  canDeactivate(component: AccountPage) {
    return component.areFormsSaved();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`canActivate` and `canDeactivate` are guards, when your app multiple roles in application, like user, admin etc, you use guards to protece them, also you use `canActivate` for pages which are accessible only for loggedin users and vice versa for `canDeactivate`

Code sample of `canActivate`

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private data: DataService
    ) {}

    canActivate(): Observable < boolean > {
        var token = this.data.getToken();
        if (token) {
            return Observable.of(true);
        } else {
            return Observable.of(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And you use it like this in routers

```
{
    path: 'user',
    component: UserComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

Comment: `canActivate` can return boolean value. You don't need to create observable of boolean value.